# Does upsert() preserve TTL in couchbase?

Tags: couchbase

This one is simple to figure out via code, but since its counter-intuitive (and not documented) I'm documenting it here:

Does Upsert (insert/update operation) preserve TTL in couchbase?

In other words, if I run this code:

```
cb.upsert('hello',{'hi':'there'},ttl=10)
cb.upsert('hello',{'hi':'there'})
```

will the documented created (and then updated) expire after 10 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, no. the 2nd upsert resets the TTL - and the document will never expire.

Note that this behavior isn't consistent across couchbase: the incr() operation (for counters) does NOT reset the TTL.